# How to fix error "404" in Power BI M query

Tags: powerbi, azure-cognitive-services, jsonresponse

I am getting error code 404 in PowerBI.

Sample Data:

> ID,    text
>
> 1, @VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.
>
> 2, @VirginAmerica plus you've added commercials to the experience..
>
> 3, @VirginAmerica I didn't today... Must mean I need to take another
>
> 4, "@VirginAmerica it's really aggressive to blast obnoxious ""entert
>
> 5, @VirginAmerica and it's a really big bad thing about it

I am trying to write sentiment score in PowerBI using M query in Microsoft cognitive services.

below is my query.

Query: (Source as table) as any =>

```
let JsonRecords = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(Source)),
JsonRequest = “{“”documents””: ” & JsonRecords & “}”,

JsonContent = Text.ToBinary(JsonRequest, TextEncoding.Ascii),
Response =
    Web.Contents(“https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics”,
        [
            Headers = [#”Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key”= APIkey,
                       #”Content-Type”=”application/json”, Accept=”application/json”],
            Content=JsonContent
        ]),
JsonResponse = Json.Document(Response,1252)
```

in
    JsonResponse (Query end)

Error:

> An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://vizguru.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment/keyPhrases' (404): Resource Not Found
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=Web
>       DataSourcePath=https://vizguru.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment/keyPhrases
>       Url=https://vizguru.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment/keyPhrases

Expected Output:

> ID,    text,   Score,
>
> 1, @VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.,    2
>
> 2, @VirginAmerica plus you've added commercials to the experience..., 3
>
> 3, @VirginAmerica I didn't today... Must mean I need to take another !,4
>
> 4, @VirginAmerica it's really aggressive to blast,     5
>
> 5, @VirginAmerica and it's a really big bad thing about it,    6

Steps Followed from this [link](https://theexcelclub.com/sentiment-analysis-with-power-bi-and-microsoft-cognitive-services).

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can repro your 404 error on my side . The reason is the text analysis endpoint:

`https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics`

not works anymore .

If you want to use azure cognitive service text analytics API, pls refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-call-api#set-up-a-request-in-postman) to find correct endpoint and ways to call text analysis service .

If you have any further concerns ,pls feel free to let me know .